# sqlite creates 2 databases when including from different directories

Tags: php, sqlite

So i got a class like this:

```
class Db {
    protected static $dbh = false;

    function connect(){
        try {
        self::$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:./test.db");
        self::$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tytul TEXT, tresc TEXT, data DATE, wazne TINYINT(1))");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

There is more to it like fetch functions etc. I have this class stored like this:

```
|otherfile.php
|admin
  |inc/db.inc
  |somefile.php
```

So my problem is when i require('db.inc'); from within somefile.php and use the class it creates a new test.db in folder "admin". But when i require it in file "otherfile.php" and use the class it creates a seperate test.db file in the same folder as "otherfile.php". How can i force it to use one file, while still using a relative path to the db?

edit:
Personally i think this would work the best:

```
function connect(){
    try {
    $dir = __DIR__.'/test.db';
    self::$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:".$dir);
    self::$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    self::$dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tytul TEXT, tresc TEXT, data DATE, wazne TINYINT(1))");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

This does work locally with my xampp setup, but doesn't work on a remote server sadly.

edit: Finally figured it out, see answer.

Thanks for the answers anyway :-)

Comment: try using a full path on your DB class when you reference the database, instead of ./

Comment: yeah that would work i know it, i was just asking if it's possible while still using a relative path

Comment: it is not possible because you will access the class from different locations and the relative path won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a path to your connection function

```
function connect($path_to_sql_db) {
  try {
    self::$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:"+$path_to_sql_db);
    self::$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    self::$dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tytul TEXT, tresc TEXT, data DATE, wazne TINYINT(1))");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


}
```

Since your files are in different places the same relative path will not work, as you are observing.

Comment: I edited the answer into my question since i can't answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, my local php setup has php > version 5.3, the version on the remote server was below 5.3 so `__DIR__` wasn't avaiable and i had to use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead, and it finally worked like intended:

```
function connect(){
    try {
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__).'/test.db';
    self::$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:".$dir);
    self::$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    self::$dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tytul TEXT, tresc TEXT, data DATE, wazne TINYINT(1))");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```